Firebase OAuth Account Linking
I am currently working on a project using Firebase Auth for the Google and Apple auth providers for a mobile app built in Flutter. For the login I am using firebae_ui_auth.
I need to link existing accounts with their Google account when they login.
Is decoding the ID Token and storing the account ID in my database what I am generally looking to do? Can I then use the ID token as a token required for routes? Or should I create my own JWT?
I currently am using am storing the account ID and cross checking it with the decoded ID token on accessing a route but this feels like it could be incorrect ID tokens expire. I am not at all knowledgeable about auth in any way.

There is plenty of documentation on account linking. Start there.

This is from the perspective of linking accounts types given by Firebase. I am linking a custom account. I'm assuming using OAuth and decoding the ID token with the firebase admin sdk is a good route upon login and registration. I was more so wondering if that same ID token , , is in common practice, used as a way to grant access to secured routes because it can expire.
